# No Puedo Acceder a un controlador Generico en C# mvc

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

buenas tardes resulta que tengo un controlador genérico con varios ActionResult y que ocupo en casi toda la aplicación, el código del controlador es el siguiente.

```
 public class Generico : Controller
{
    public WebDBTContext db = new WebDBTContext();

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetPartidas(int id)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var mtorequerimiento = db.MtoRequerimientos.Where(c => c.MtoProcedimientoId == id)
            .OrderBy(r => r.Partida);
        return Json(mtorequerimiento);
    }

    public JsonResult LoadLicitantes()
    {
        List<MtoProveedor> Proveedores = new List<MtoProveedor>();

            Proveedores = db.MtoProveedores.ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = Proveedores, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }

    public ActionResult GetProcedimientos(string term)
    {
        var user = db.MtoUsuarios.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        var Result = from c in db.MtoProcedimientos
                     where c.NoLicitacion.ToString().Contains(term) && c.MtoCompaniaId==user.MtoCompaniaId
                     orderby c.NoLicitacion
                     select new Item
                     {
                         id = c.MtoProcedimientoId.ToString(),
                         value = c.NoLicitacion.ToString()
                     };

        return Json(Result.Take(10).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    public JsonResult getDataBindClave(int id)
    {
        var listOfertas = db.MtoOfertas.Where(o => o.MtoRequerimientoId == id).ToList();

        return Json(listOfertas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

en mi layout tengo en una variable la ruta.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _urlBase = '@Url.Content("~/")';             
</script>
```

ahora bien cuando quiero ocupar el controlador por jquery

```
$('#NoLicitacion').autocomplete({
    source: _urlBase + "Generico/GetProcedimientos",
    select: function (event, ui) {
        GetPartidas(ui.item.id);
        $("#MtoProcedimientoId").val(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

sin embargo me dice que la ruta no existe.

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
```

No se encuentra el recurso.
Descripción: HTTP 404. El recurso que está buscando (o una de sus dependencias) se puede haber quitado, haber cambiado de nombre o no estar disponible temporalmente. Revise la dirección URL siguiente y asegúrese de que está escrita correctamente.

Dirección URL solicitada: /Generico/GetProcedimientos

Información de versión: Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.7.2558.0

Comment: Hola. El parámetro `term` dónde se lo estás enviando?

Comment: se supone el autocomplete toma automaticamente el dato del campo donde se dispare el evento en este caso MtoProcedimientoId

Comment: perdón el dato donde lo toma es NoLicitacion

Comment: edita la pregunta y agrega lo que tienes en el startup.cs

Answer (score 1):

modifica tu metodo y agrega la llamada ajax mas o menos asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#NoLicitacion').autocomplete({  
            source: function (request, response) {  
                var autocompleteUrl = 'Generico/GetProcedimientos' + '?term=' + request.term;  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: autocompleteUrl,  
                    type: 'GET',  
                    cache: false,  
                    dataType: 'json',  
                    success: function (json) {  
                        response($.map(json, function (data) {  
                            return {  
                                label: data.Id,  
                                value: data.Value  
                            };  
                        }));  
                    },  
                    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                        console.log('revisar Error', textStatus, errorThrown);  
                    }  
                });  
            },  
            minLength: 1,  
            select: function (event, ui) {  
                 GetPartidas(ui.item.id);
              $("#MtoProcedimientoId").val(ui.item.id);
            }  
        });  
    });  
</script>
```